# Invoke Java class or method from Airflow

Tags: java, python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I want to invoke few java methods from an Airflow task(s) since I already have lots of code written in java including validation, cleansing, some business logic and I don't want to rewrite that in Python again.

I am using Airflow 2.1.0

I know there is a way to invoke a jar using BashOperator

```
jar_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='java',
    bash_command='java -jar somejar.jar',
    dag=dag
)
```

But is there any way using which I can call any specific java class or method directly from the task itself, otherwise I have to create many small jars for each of my logic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you convert your java application into a java spring boot application so that you can call the end point?

Comment: @PraneethKumar yes that is also possible, but for that I need to create many rest end points. I was hoping for a direct solution if available in Airflow. If not, I can try this

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/java.html) for the `java` command?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `java -cp somejar.jar SomeClass` to run a different main method.

Answer (score 0):

```
java_command = 'java -cp .:{lib_path}/* class_name args'
java_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="java_task",
    bash_command=java_command,
)
```

**lib_path**=Path to directory where your required jar file is present
**class_name** = com.x.y.**ClassName**
args = Argument should be in **space seperated** if your class is expecting more than one arguments